# Kotlin EditText

Tags: arrays, kotlin, android-edittext

Hi I have the following question, so far I have been using Java, but I started learning Kotlin. When I use EditText, how can I store more than one integer or double value. With Java, I do it like this:

```
            double res;
            int f = 0;

            String[] values = editText.getText().toString().split("\\s");

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                res = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(values[f]));
                f++;

            }

            double value1 = Double.valueOf(values[0]);
            double value2 = Double.valueOf(values[1]);
            double value3 = Double.valueOf(values[2]);
            double value4 = Double.valueOf(values[3]);
            double value5 = Double.valueOf(values[4]);
            double value6 = Double.valueOf(values[5]);
```

I use 'for' and store each value entered in the edit text below. How can I do this using Kotlin?
With Android studio I can convert the code, I did it, but when I press the button to display my result, the application turns off:

```
        var res: Double
        var f = 0
        var i: Int

        val values: List<String> = edit_text.toString().split("\\s")

        for (i in 0..5) {
            res = values[f].toDouble()
            f++
        }

        val value1 = java.lang.Double.valueOf(values[0])
        val value2 = java.lang.Double.valueOf(values[1])
        val value3 = java.lang.Double.valueOf(values[2])
        val value4 = java.lang.Double.valueOf(values[3])
        val value5 = java.lang.Double.valueOf(values[4])
        val value6 = java.lang.Double.valueOf(values[5])

        textView.setText(String.format("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f", value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EditText have nothing to do with what you want to achieve, as it's part of Andorid SDK, not Java or Kotlin.
From what I understood, you want to parse input values, add them, but also display. Try something like:

```
    val values: List<String> = edit_text.toString().split("\\s")
    
    val amountOfValues: Int= values.size
    val valuesAsDoubles: List<Double> = values.map{ it.toDouble() }
    val result: Double = valuesAsDoubles.sum()
    val stringToDisplay: String = valuesAsDoubles.joinToString("")
    textView.setText(stringToDisplay)
```

Learn about collection manipulation, with eg. [map{}](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) .